# Changing month-end df into a more usable format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large df of this structure:

```
structure(list(Month_End = c("2022-23", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", 
"Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2021-22", "Mar", "Feb", 
"Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", 
"Apr", "2020-21", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", 
"Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2019-20", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", 
"2018-19", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", 
"Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2017-18", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", 
"Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2016-17", 
"Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", 
"Jun", "May", "Apr", "2015-16", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", 
"Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2014-15", "Mar", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", 
"May", "Apr", "2013-14", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", 
"Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2012-13", "Mar", "Feb", 
"Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", 
"Apr", "2011-12", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", 
"Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2010-11", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", 
"2009-10", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", 
"Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2008-09", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", 
"Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2007-08", 
"Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", 
"Jun", "May", "Apr", "2006-07", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", 
"Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2005-06", "Mar", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", 
"May", "Apr", "2004-05", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", 
"Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2003-04", "Mar", "Feb", 
"Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", 
"Apr", "2002-03", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", 
"Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", "2001-02", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr", 
"2000-01", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep", "Aug", 
"Jul", "Jun", "May", "Apr"), Val = c(NA, "2000", "2000", "2500", 
"3500", "5000", "4000", "2000", "3000", "2500", NA, "2000", "2000", 
"2000", "2000", "2500", "2000", "2000", "2500", "2000", "2500", 
"2000", "2000", NA, "2500", "2000", "2500", "2000", "2500", "2000", 
"2500", "2000", "2000", "2500", "6000", "5000", NA, "7500", "3500", 
"2000", "4000", "2000", "3500", "8500", "3000", "3000", "2000", 
"2000", "4000", NA, "7500", "2000", "3000", "4500", "2000", "2500", 
"8000", "7500", "8000", "4000", "2000", "2500", NA, "5000", "2000", 
"2000", "6000", "3000", "2500", "6000", "6000", "2500", "5000", 
"2500", "2000", NA, "2000", "2000", "2500", "3500", "2000", "2500", 
"5000", "2500", "2000", "2000", "2500", "2000", NA, "4500", "5500", 
"6750", "4500", "2000", "2750", "10000", "4500", "2000", "9500", 
"4500", "2000", NA, "6500", "2000", "2500", "6500", "2500", "2000", 
"8000", "2000", "3500", "6500", "2000", "2500", NA, "9000", "2000", 
"2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "4500", "2000", "2500", "3500", 
"2500", "4000", NA, "5500", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2500", 
"4000", "2000", "3500", "7000", "2500", "5500", NA, "7500", "2500", 
"2500", "2500", "3000", "3500", "5500", "3000", "4500", "6000", 
"7500", "6000", NA, "6000", "2500", "2500", "1500", "2500", "4000", 
"4000", "5000", "4000", "5000", "4000", "4000", NA, "6500", "4000", 
"4000", "3000", "5000", "4000", "5000", "4000", "4000", "5000", 
"4000", "4000", NA, "3600", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1600", 
"2000", "1600", "1600", "2000", "1600", "1600", NA, "2250", "1800", 
"1900", "2500", "2000", "2500", "2000", "2000", "2500", "2000", 
"2000", "2500", NA, "1600", "1600", "1250", "1500", "2200", "2750", 
"3150", "1800", "2350", "2200", "2750", "2200", NA, "2050", "2000", 
"2500", "1500", "950", "1450", "2000", "2500", "1750", "6000", 
"2500", "3000", NA, "4750", "4650", "4650", "4500", "5000", "2000", 
"3500", "1100", "2550", "7500", "2500", "3000", NA, "4500", "1200", 
"4300", "5250", "950", "1650", "4400", "950", "950", "5500", 
"3650", "2300", NA, "2900", "600", "3650", "6500", "950", "2550", 
"5900", "2350", "2800", "5500", "2200", "2300", NA, "3700", "750", 
"2650", "4200", "2650", "1350", "600", "600", "2200", "2150", 
"600", "1250", NA, "2000", "1500", "1300", "850", "600", "750", 
"600", "1300", "1350", "2150", "750", "600")), row.names = c(NA, 
-296L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'd like to change the 'Month_End' column to be the structure of %Y-%m rather than have a row that reads "2022-23" followed by a Dec, Nov, Oct etc. Does anyone know how to make this change? If it can be done dynamically if the df updated, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell again, which outcome you prefer? One column with values e.g. `2021-11` for November 2021? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(
    Year = zoo::na.locf(if_else(grepl("^2", Month_End), Month_End, NA_character_)),
    Year = if_else(Month_End %in% c("Mar", "Feb", "Jan"),
                   sub("20(..)-(..)", "20\\2", Year),
                   sub("20(..)-(..)", "20\\1", Year)),
    Month_End = paste(Year, sprintf("%02i", match(Month_End, month.abb)), sep = "-")
  ) %>%
  select(-Year) %>%
  print(n=16)
# # A tibble: 296 × 2
#    Month_End Val  
#    <chr>     <chr>
#  1 2022-NA   NA   
#  2 2022-12   2000 
#  3 2022-11   2000 
#  4 2022-10   2500 
#  5 2022-09   3500 
#  6 2022-08   5000 
#  7 2022-07   4000 
#  8 2022-06   2000 
#  9 2022-05   3000 
# 10 2022-04   2500 
# 11 2021-NA   NA   
# 12 2022-03   2000 
# 13 2022-02   2000 
# 14 2022-01   2000 
# 15 2021-12   2000 
# 16 2021-11   2500 
# # … with 280 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

You can include `%>% filter(!grepl("-NA$", Month_End))` to remove the rows that marked the year ranges.